# Fundmental group of cone

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex  with an edge loop $\alpha=(a_0,a_1,a_2)$.

Let $X$ be a simplicial complex consisting of $K$ together with another additional vertex $b$ in the center, connected to all the vertices $a_0,a_1,a_2$.

How do we show that $\pi_1(X,a_0)$ is the quotient group of $\pi_1(|K|,a_0)$ by adding the relation $[\alpha]=1$, where $\alpha=(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_0)$, the edge loop?

I was thinking in the direction of van Kampen's theorem, however I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't the edge loop trivial anyway, since it can be contracted over the 2-simplex?

Comment: @StefanHamcke good point, I will edit my question shortly